# If two matrices are similar, the geometric multiplicities of their eigenvalues are the same

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

#### Problem

> Let $A$ and $B$ be similar matrices. Prove that the geometric multiplicities of the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are the same. [Hint: show that, if $B=P^{-1}AP$, then every eigenvector of $B$ is of the form $P^{-1}\vec{v}$ for some eigenvector $\vec{v}$ of A].

#### Attempted Proof

Write $A \vec{v} = \lambda \vec{v}$.   Since $B=P^{-1}AP$, this is equivalent to saying
$$B (P^{-1}\vec{v})=P^{-1}APP^{-1}\vec{v} = P^{-1}A\vec{v} = \lambda (P^{-1} \vec{v})$$

Since $P^{-1} \vec{v}$ is an eigenvector of $B$ only for eigenvalues of $A$, the dimensions of the eigenspaces must be the same.

Is this proof complete?

Comment: also show that every eigenvector of $B$ is of this form (just for completeness)

Comment: @Blah How would I do so?

Comment: If $Bv=\lambda v$ then $B(P^{-1}Pv)=\lambda P^{-1}Pv$,set $w=Pv$

Answer (score 1):

You should also show that every eigenvector of $B$ is of this form (just for completeness):

If $Bv=\lambda v$ then $B(P^{-1}Pv)=\lambda P^{-1}Pv$. Set $w=Pv$ here. Observe that  $w$ is an eigenvector of $A$. Indeed,  $BP^{-1} = P^{-1}A$, so 
$$P^{-1}Aw = \lambda P^{-1}w$$

(Based on a comment by [Blah](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/693701/if-two-matrices-are-similar-the-geometric-multiplicities-of-their-eigenvalues-a#comment1453612_693701))